# Find regex occurrances on block device (line length buffer issue)

Tags: bash, sed, grep, python, perl

I'm trying to find all numbers on two block devices that start with a `#` character, are between 1635700000 and 1653699999, and end either with a null character (`\0`) or a linux newline (`\0xA`).

I came up with this `grep` that certainly isn't elegant:

```
grep --only-matching --byte-offset --text -Pa '#1635[7-9][0-9]{5}(\x0|$)|#163[6-9][0-9]{6}(\x0|$)|#164[0-9]{7}(\x0|$)|#165[0-2][0-9]{6}(\x0|$)|#1653[0-6][0-9]{5}(\x0|$)' /dev/device
```

Even though it can't be typed and executed like this, here's the same statement with some newlines to make it more readable.

```
grep --only-matching --byte-offset --text -Pa '
 #1635[7-9][0-9]{5}(\x0|$)
|#163[6-9][0-9]{6}(\x0|$)
|#164[0-9]{7}(\x0|$)
|#165[0-2][0-9]{6}(\x0|$)
|#1653[0-6][0-9]{5}(\x0|$)
' /dev/device
```

This worked on one of the block devices, but on the other after some but not all output, it stopped with the error:

```
grep: exceeded PCRE's line length limit
```

I'm guessing the failing block device has a longer stretch of bytes that don't have a `\0` or `\0xA` character, crossing the line length limit threshold.

So, I tried changing NULL characters to newlines:

```
sed 's/\x0/\n/g' /dev/device | grep ...
```

But, it stopped for about the same reason:

```
sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX
```

How can I find what I'm trying to find on this second block device?  Pretty sure it will need to be a different utility that either uses a larger input buffer or that doesn't read full lines, or perhaps even a custom perl/python/C/C++ program.

I do need the output to be one line per match found, including the byte offset and number found.

Modifying the block device is not an option.  There's going to be tens of thousands of results, so searching by hand in something like a hex editor isn't an option either.

Comment: It looks like there is [bgrep](https://github.com/rsharo/bgrep) for exactly this situation, although I've never tried it. I also wonder if the problem would reproduce if you were to *not* use the PCRE engine.

Comment: What if you replace `#` by `\n#` and remove the rest of the lines after 11 bytes using sed or perl? The lines to grep will then be very short...

Comment: @larsks I will look at bgrep.  I'm using Perl because that's the only way I could find to grep for a NULL character.

Comment: @choroba I unfortunately can't assume anything about what will be before the `#` character.  `sed` has the same type of issue, since I ran into the `sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX` issue.

Comment: @larsks Unfortunately, it looks like bgrep can't look for a regex.  It can do a bit more than fixed strings either by hex byte or ASCII, but it doesn't look like it can look for a number within a range like I need.

Comment: Maybe try to reduce the search space first? Something like `grep -aoP '#16\d+?(\0|$)' /dev/device | grep ...` where the second grep is the one you're currently using?

Comment: You could hexdump the device first (using `od` or `xxd`), and then perform your search on the output, which would be regular text with consistent line ends. Matching patterns that cross lines would be difficult.

Comment: @larsks Very true.  Taking on matching multi line patterns would be a way to do this.

Comment: @terdon Unfortunately, attempting to reduce the search space that way still runs it through the PCRE engine and creates the same problem.  But, the idea of reducing the search space first set me on the right path!  I'm about to post the solution I used, and of course credit you with the inspiration for it.  The idea of reducing search space was the key insight!

Answer (score 2):

In a comment above, @terdon gave the key insight about reducing the search space first.  By using the extended grep pattern syntax to reduce the maximum line length given to the perl (PCRE) grep pattern syntax, I was able to get this to work.

```
grep --only-matching --byte-offset --text -E '#[0-9]{10}.' /dev/device | grep --only-matching --text -P '[0-9]*:#1635[7-9][0-9]{5}(\x0|$)|[0-9]*:#163[6-9][0-9]{6}(\x0|$)|[0-9]*:#164[0-9]{7}(\x0|$)|[0-9]*:#165[0-2][0-9]{6}(\x0|$)|[0-9]*:#1653[0-6][0-9]{5}(\x0|$)' /dev/device
```

Even though it can't be typed and executed like this, here's the same statement with some newlines to make it more readable.

```
grep --only-matching --byte-offset --text -E 
   '#[0-9]{10}.'
   /dev/device
| grep --only-matching --text -P '
    [0-9]*:#1635[7-9][0-9]{5}(\x0|$)
   |[0-9]*:#163[6-9][0-9]{6}(\x0|$)
   |[0-9]*:#164[0-9]{7}(\x0|$)
   |[0-9]*:#165[0-2][0-9]{6}(\x0|$)
   |[0-9]*:#1653[0-6][0-9]{5}(\x0|$)
   ' /dev/device
```

The extended grep pattern syntax engine doesn't have a line length limitation that I ran into, and reduces the maximum line length given to the perl (PCRE) pattern syntax engine.

Comment: If there's something like `#1635700000` with a newline after, that first grep won't find it, since the `.` in the regex can't match the newline. You could probably preprocess the file with e.g. `tr '\0' '\n'` to change NULs to newlines, and then use `grep -E '#[0-9]{10}$'`. (`tr` works a byte (or character) at a time, and doesn't care about lines, so it shouldn't have a length limit.) Also, it'd be easier to check if number is in the required range with something like awk: no need for the complex regex, just something like `awk -F: '$2 >= 1635700000 && $2 <= 1653699999'`

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks, whoops, I was missing some results!  Changing the first grep to `#[0-9{10}(.|$)` seems to also do the trick, but I'll try using your way too, and it's certainly more elegant.  Thanks also for the `awk`.  I definitely need to start learning that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using bash(1), grep(1), and perl(1):

```
 1  #!/bin/bash
 2  grep -P -a -b -o '#\d{10}(\000|$)' \
 3  | perl -ne '/(\d{10})/; print if 1635700000 <= $1 && $1 <= 1653699999' \
 4  | perl -pe 'chop; /\000/ ? do {chop; $_ .= "\\000\n"} : do {$_ .= "\\n\n"}'
```

Line 1 tells the shell this is a Bash script.

Lines 2-4 form a command pipeline.

Line 2 invokes grep(1):

- Option '-P' specifies that the pattern should be interpreted as a Perl-compatible regular expression.
- Option '-a' specifies that binary input should be processed as text.
- Option '-b', combined with '-o', specifies that the byte offset of the matching part should be printed before each line of output.
- Option '-o' specifies that only the matched parts should be printed.
- Argument '#\d{10}($|\000)' is a regular expression pattern -- a number sign, followed by ten decimal digits, followed by either end-of-line or NUL.  On Unix/ Linux, the regular expression end-of-line '$' meta-character matches ASCII carriage return (problem statement '\0xA').  The regular expression may fail to find ASCII carriage returns when run on platforms with different newline encoding (e.g. CR-LF on MS-DOS, LF on classic Mac OS, etc.).

Line 3 is a Perl one-line filter that only passes lines whose numeric part is within the desired range.

Line 4 is a Perl one-liner that makes the terminating newline or NUL visible.

Here is a sample run:

```
52:#1647787407\n
70:#1644931194\n
84:#1651134631\000
154:#1646920743\n
```